# Facebook doesn't detect video while sharing my own page

Tags: facebook, html, video, facebook-opengraph

I have a website with many video pages. There is only one video on each page.
When i share a link of one of these pages on facebook, it is not considered as a video, but only a standard article.

Thumbnail, Title and Decription are well displayed. But instead of displaying the thumbnail, i would like Facebook to display the video.

I'm using [videoJS](http://www.videojs.com/) as video player.

Here is my html header:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Page Title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Page Description" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="ADMIN-ID" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="APP-ID" />
<meta property="og:image" content="/path/to/the/thumbnail.jpg" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video" />
<meta property="og:url" content="www.domain.com/video.html" />
<meta property="og:video" content="www.domain.com/video.mp4" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="video/mp4" />
```

And my video :

```
<video id="video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin shadow"  controls preload="auto" width="686" height="386" poster="path/to/the/poster.png">
 <source src="path/to/the/video.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
</video>
```

Here are the Facebook Debug Tool informations :

```
{
   "url": "http:\/\/www.domaine.com\/video.mp4",
   "type": "video\/mp4",
   "width": 686,
   "height": 386
}
```

and

```
status :

Video embedding on Facebook enabled
```

Thanks for your help and your comprehension, i'am a newbe in Facebook API.

Comment: Do you have HTTPS URLs for your video files in the OG meta tags as well?

Comment: no, everything is HTTP

Comment: You will need HTTPS sources as well, since most Facebook users surf over HTTPS already (and Facebook is in the process of getting the rest of them there).

Comment: @CBroe - Sorry for this late answer. I cannot modify my website in order to use HTTPS. But with your comment, i change my Facebook account setting not to use HTTPS, only HTTP, and it works fine ! I believe you were right. Post the answer for upvote and solve if you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have HTTPS URLs for your video files in the OG meta tags as well?

**You will need HTTPS sources as well**, since most Facebook users surf over HTTPS already (and Facebook is in the process of getting the rest of them there).

Comment: Thanks, i cannot set up HTTPS for now, but disabling HTTPS in Facebook settings allow me to post and view the link as video from my own account. Your answer should be right. Thanks for your help.