# How to embed into Facebook using PHP SDK

Tags: html5-video, facebook-php-sdk, video.js

I have been trying really hard to get this working but with no sign of hope. I summoned my powers to do the right thing but with no success.

I am wondering if someone have embed videojs player into facebook feed

A thought in the right direction will be appreciated.

Comment: Were you finally able to do this? if so please anwer your own question as would be really helpful for other people (like me :)

Comment: No, I couldn't do that. It seems that FB was only creating thumbnails out of known video sites (e.g. youtube, dailymotion, etc)

Answer (score 0):

From here : https://www.jwplayer.com/blog/publish-your-videos-to-facebook-with-a-jw-player/ it seem there is securities limitation. Facebook want a secure url with https. If not, Facebook make a link toward your website's page...

Of course, you have to use the OpenGraph protocol : http://ogp.me/
Like here : [Facebook doesn't detect video while sharing my own page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784356/facebook-doesnt-detect-video-while-sharing-my-own-page)

Best regard